# Debugging a simple jQuery function; wondering if there's a conflict with another code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").on("click", function(){
         jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF"); 
     });
     jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").on("blur", function(){           
         jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").css("background-color", "#CC0000"); 
     });
 });
```

This is the code, it's supposed to add the onclick and onblur functions to change the background colors of my input field but it doesn't work.

jQuery code is being loaded before this script and this script is being loaded in a separate file inside the html after it.

What did I do wrong? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: After trying everything in the answers, I tried Chase's suggestion in the comments.
it worked like a charm! So the final code is now an inline script after the jQuery is loaded and it's like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").bind("click", function(){ 
jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF"); });
jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").bind("blur", function(){ 
jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").css("background-color", "#CC0000"); });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the developer console in Chrome?

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "doesn't work"

Comment: This won't fix whatever problem you're having, but for future reference; inside an event handler you can use `this` to target the current HTML element, so you can replace your `jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").css()` calls with `jQuery(this).css()`, you can also pass an event map to `on()` to save you having to target the element more than once.

Comment: onClick and onBlur events aren't added.

Comment: I couldn't paste the whole HTML, Website is located at http://epasaportkaydi.com/

Comment: I would suggest using `.bind()` instead of `.on()` for versions prior to 1.7 ("`As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.` - http://api.jquery.com/on/")

Comment: Chase, you're a genius! That was the problem. replacing the .on() with .bind() fixed it right away! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Chase would be great if you can add that as answer or I can self answer, either way, thanks again :)

Comment: No problem =) Added it into the answers for future searchers. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `.bind()` instead of `.on()` for versions prior to 1.7.

`"As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers."`

[api.jquery.com/on/](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 3):

You're loading your jQuery-reliant scripts before jQuery has loaded.

```
  <script src="/templates/e-pasaporthome/javascript/styleForms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery.nivo.slider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Instead, put jQuery first;

```
  <script src="/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/templates/e-pasaporthome/javascript/styleForms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery.nivo.slider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I couldn't move the place the jquery is being loaded (it's being loaded by another plugin)

so I updated the page and added the jQuery-reliant script as an inline script after the jquery.min.js and it still doesn't work. the console section in firebug doesn't show anything either.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the jQuery file in the first place.. If you have done so then Hit the F12 in your browser and check to see if you see any errors in the console section of the browser..

Also are you using another javascript libraries..?

Comment: In the future, this is not really an answer, but would be more suited as a comment!

Comment: Why don't you use the latest jQuery version hosted by google cdn and then try again... <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Also why don't you use the jQuery.noconflict() object and try again..jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // Your code here
  });
})(jQuery);

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything in the answers, I tried Chase's suggestion in the comments. it worked like a charm! So the final code is now an inline script after the jQuery is loaded and it's like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").bind("click", function(){
jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF"); });
jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").bind("blur", function(){ 
jQuery("#bfCaptchaEntry").css("background-color", "#CC0000"); });
});
```